# ToDictionary not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following code, I am having trouble returning a Dictionary.

```
[JsonProperty]
public virtual IDictionary<Product, int> JsonProducts
{
    get
    {
        return Products.ToDictionary<Product, int>(x => x.Key, v => v.Value);
    }
}

public virtual IDictionary<Product, int> Products { get; set; }
```

I get the following errors..

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer)' has some invalid arguments
>
> cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Func'
>
> cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer

There is nothing special about the Product class. it is simply defined as

```
class Product 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Brad Christie: `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` and there is an extension method `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.ToDictionary` defined in the static class `Enumerable`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why do you use

```
Products.ToDictionary<Product, int>(x => x.Key, v => v.Value)
```

instead of just

```
Products.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, v => v.Value)
```

?

---

That's because

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector
);
```

Take a look to the number (3) and types of generic type parameters (Func).

which means that you need to call it:

```
Products.ToDictionary<KeyValuePair<Product, int>, Product, int>(x => x.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Comment: No overload for method 'ToDictionary' takes 0 arguments

Comment: Why would you convert a Dictionary to a Dictionary? Shouldn't returning "Products" be same same as OriginalType.ToOriginalType?

Comment: @Brad: Maybe to return a clone of the original dictionary so that the original can't be mutated?

Comment: @Brad: Why do you address your question to ME? Address it to OP!

Comment: It's an experiment. I am trying to serialize the class to JSON, but nHibernate Proxies are interfering. I was hoping returning non-proxied code might help in its cooperation.

Comment: @abatishchev: Because you offered it as a viable solution, and I was curious as to your logic. I see a public property with the IDictionary interface, then I see almost a mirror property, decorated with a JSON attribute, trying to retrieve the same information. Am I the only one seeing a redundancy? And though I may not always have an answer on this site, it's interesting to see the approaches people take (and I like to learn by asking questions of why the approach was a fit in the poster's eyes)

Comment: @Stacey: Look at my last edit to see how to properly call generic function directly, i.e. without omitting type parameters

Comment: @Brad: Okay, sorry. In fact the same methods signatures are mentioned in OP's post so I just copied it untouched. But changed method's body to get rid from the compiler error

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify the generic type parameters explicitly. The types in `ToDictionary<T1, T2>` are not `T1 = TKey` and `T2 = TValue` (where `TKey` is the type of the key of the resulting dictionary and `TValue` is the type of the resulting value in the dictionary).

The overload of `ToDictionary` that accepts two generic type parameters has `T = TSource` and `V = TKey`. Here, `TSource = KeyValuePair<Product, int>`. Further, you are invoking the [overload of `ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548554.aspx) that has two parameters. The first parameter is a map from `T1 -> T2` and the second is an `IEqualityComparer<T2>`. But `x => x.Key` is not a map from `KeyValuePair<Product, int>` to `int` and `v => v.Value` is not an `IEqualityComparer<int>`.

When you don't specify the generic type parameters explicitly, the compiler inspects the types of `x => x.Key` and `v => v.Value` and looks at the various overloads of `ToDictionary`. There are four

1. `ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)`
2. `ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, IEqualityComparer<TKey>)`
3. `ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, Func<TSource, TElement>)`
4. `ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, Func<TSource, TElement>, IEqualityComparer<TKey>)`

Note that it can immediately rule out 1. and 4. because they have the wrong number of parameters (2 and 4 respectively whereas you are invoking an overload that needs three parameters (the third is the hidden first parameter because you are invoking an extension method)). It can rule out 2. because the last parameter can not be converted to an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for any `T`. This leaves the last overload. It is able to deduce that `x => x.Key` is a `Func<KeyValuePair<Product, int>, Product>`, that `v => v.Value` is a `Func<KeyValuePair<Product, int>, int>` and therefore that you are invoking

```
ToDictionary<KeyValuePair<Product, int>, Product, int>(
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Product, int>>,
    Func<KeyValuePair<Product, int>, Product>,
    Func<KeyValuePair<Product, int>, int>
)
```

If you wanted to specify the type parameters explicitly you would have to say

```
Products.ToDictionary<KeyValuePair<Product, int>, Product, int>(
    x => x.Key,
    v => v.Value
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not actually cloning the Product instances, you can just do:

```
public virtual IDictionary<Product, int> JsonProducts
{
    get
    {
        return new Dictionary(Products);
    }
}
```